What does resonance means in inductive coupling?
From what I understood: resonance helps achieve higher coupling coefficients in coils.
What does it mean and how is it achieved?

Search for LC circuit or tuned circuit.

This deserves a (more) serious answer.
Inductive coupling can be well analyzed by considering the two coils as a weakly coupled transformer. That is, as a circuit analysis problem (no need to invoke Maxwell's equations, at least if the transformer parameters are known or can be measured).
A capacitor at the input side will increase the current through the primary, and thus increase the flux penetrating the secondary. The complication is that the inductance at the primary varies with the load on the secondary, (and the degree of coupling!) which in turn can be influenced by any matching components (i.e. capacitors) at the secondary side.
